# Non-Integrable models in 1+1D

Tags: classical-mechanics, chaos-theory, integrable-systems

Is it possible to have a non-integrable system in (1+1)D in Classical Physics? For some reason, I get the intuition that there shouldn't be any such systems. What if we consider (1+1)D systems in Quantum Physics?

Can anyone please clarify this for me and provide some examples?

Edit 1 :

Here (1+1)D refers to 1 spatial dimension and 1 temporal dimension

Edit 2 :

I would really prefer for the system to have a Hamiltonian ideally but not strictly so.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the "system"? In other words, does it have to be a Hamiltonian system?

Comment: @probably_someone I would really prefer for it to have a Hamiltonian ideally but not strictly so.

Comment: Does this mean for a single particle (ie a 2D phase space)?

Comment: @jacob1729 In classical physics this just means a 2D phase space (x,p)

Comment: FWIW, a generic field theories in 1+1D is non-integrable.

Comment: @Qmechanic Can you please give me any example? Actually I am specifically interested in CMcal and QMcal scenarios but if there are Classical Field Theories like that they might be of interest to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the system is continuous and smooth, then your intuition is correct and we'll find only regular behavior in its 2D phase space (position and momentum). That's a well-known result, the [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem#Discussion).

In such smooth systems we need to have [at least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#Minimum_complexity_of_a_chaotic_system) three dimensions for non-regular motion to take place. A time-dependent forcing can provide the necessary extra space, and a text-book example is the [Duffing oscillator](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Duffing_oscillator).

Comment: This is helpful. Could you please also point me towards any reference when I consider the same for Quantum Mechanical systems? Or if the same holds true there as well then a quantum analogue of the theorem?

Comment: @Nitin I don't recall any such neat result for QM. I'd say that the questions (on classical and quantum physics) are distinct enough to merit being posted separately - so I suggest you make this question only about classical systems and post a new one on quantum integrability.